# MIDI loopback on Linux

Tags: linux, midi, loopback

I have a USB to MIDI adaptor, and I'm trying to implement a simple loopback.  I want to read from the MIDI in, and echo it directly to the MIDI out.

I've been using `amidi` to both send and receive raw MIDI commands.  Each operation works well independently, but I can't combine the two.  The system throws an error because the first instance of the program blocks the second.

```
$ amidi -p hw:1,0,0 -S < `amidi -p hw:1,0,0 -d`
ALSA lib rawmidi_hw.c:233:(snd_rawmidi_hw_open) open /dev/snd/midiC1D0 failed: Device or resource busy
cannot open port "hw:1,0,0": Device or resource busy
-bash: `/usr/bin/amidi -p hw:1,0,0 -d`: ambiguous redirect
```

How can I echo MIDI in to out?

Comment: `amidi` is a tool used to handle the RawMIDI interface, which interacts with a proper hardware MIDI device (lower level stuff). On most use-cases what you want is to deal with the Sequencer interface via `aseqdump`, `aconnect`, `aplaymidi` and `arecordmidi`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect MIDI ports, use `aconnect`; this also works for connecting a port to itself.
(To get a list of possible ports, run `aconnect -lio`.)

Comment: `aconnect 20:0 20:0` worked great, even though both the input and output ports are the same.  It also continues to let me use `aplaymidi` at the same time.

Comment: @Rachie, I managed to loop back MIDI to the same device with this solution. However, /dev/midi is busy and I cannot send extra commands to the device. I would like to use my own program. How can I send midi commands if this loopback is on?

Comment: @FERcsI Send them with the ALSA sequencer. But that would be a different question.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it out. I used midi directly with /dev so far, and I don't know much about Alsa. (I did and do not need anything beyond sending a receiving SysFx messages and sometimes basic ones. to my midi devices)